# convert back the $_GET array to the original URL query

Tags: php

I have an associative array called $new_get which comes from the original array of $_GET. The difference is that I modified somes of the keys and values that I will after need to echo to make a new URL.

I simply want to convert back this $new_get to it's original form, like :

```
?something=this&page=2
```

My $new_get looks like :

```
$new_get = array (
'something' => 'this',
'page' => '2'
);
```

Comment: Just store the original `$_GET` as `$new_get`. You'll still have access to the original `$_GET` array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply do that :

```
$query = "?" .http_build_query($new_get);
```

if your $new_get is built the same way than $_GET.

Here is a function of my own to make a new URL Query based on the actual one :

```
// the array_of_queries_to_change will be numbered, the values in it will replace the old values of the link. example : 'array_of_queries_to_change[0] = "?page=4";'.
// the returned value is a completed query, with the "?", then the query. It includes the current page's one and the new ones added/changed. 
function ChangeQuery($array_of_queries_to_change)
{
    $array_of_queries_to_change_count = count($array_of_queries_to_change); // count how much db we have in total. count the inactives too. 
    $new_get = $_GET;
    $i0 = 0;
//  echo "///" .($get_print = print_r($_GET, true)) ."///<br />";
//  echo "///" .($get_print = print_r($new_get, true)) ."///<br />";

    while ($i0 < $array_of_queries_to_change_count)
    {
        $array_of_keys_of_array_of_queries_to_change = array_keys($array_of_queries_to_change);
        $new_get[$array_of_keys_of_array_of_queries_to_change[$i0]] = $array_of_queries_to_change[$array_of_keys_of_array_of_queries_to_change[$i0]];
        $i0++;
    }

    $query = "?" .http_build_query($new_get);
    return $query;
}

/*// example of use : 

$array_of_queries_to_change = array (
'page' => '2',
'a key' => 'a value' 
);

$new_query = ChangeQuery($array_of_queries_to_change);

echo $new_query;
*/
```